# How to QUE visitors into a Waiting Area on my site

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have developed a web-based online registration system for one of our clients, using PHP, jquery and ajax and  MySQL as the backend. The site is sitting on a dedicated LINUX Server  hosted at our ISP.

The challenge I have  is that the site crashes and falls over as around 2500 people try to enter when registrations open. From what we can see is that hundreds of participants open up the registration page, and then continually hits the page refresh. The page itself makes a MySQL db call and returns the button that gets clicked on when registration opens.

I have thought off load balancing, but it is not viable at this stage. Is there a way one can develop a QUEING system whereby the system allows for example a blocks of let’s say 300 people at a time to continue or register whilst putting the balance of the other people in a waiting area with a script that displays the position that person is in that queue?

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Do you **really** expect people to be patient enough and wait in your queue?

Comment: I'd recommend really optimising your code and looking into using [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org) if you're not already. If people keep refreshing then why not display some kind of message to reassure them that their registration is being submitted.

Comment: 2500 people, that's not a big number, you should really look into either getting more resources on your server or optimising your infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but as **mvp** mentioned in a comment that " Do you really expect people to be patient enough and wait in your queue? " . This may be not a good idea. But still you can implement it.

Whenever a user comes to registration page, you have to do the following steps:

a) count the entries in the table (you need to create a **queue table**, where you will need to make entries for each visitor to the registration page).

b) If total count in queue table is equal to (say 300) , then redirect user to the waiting page. At waiting page, you can display information about his/her position using jquery ajax by making calls to a script which will count current users etc etc.

c) If total count is less than (say 300), then display the registration page to the user, and make an entry in the queue table along with session id (unique id for each user) and time. It is good to take time in consideration, because visitors may come and will stay on registration page doing nothing. So you have to set a time limit (say 10 mins) to stay on the registration to free up the queue.

d) After user completes registration, then delete the entry from the queue table for that user using session id.

But still remember that it is not a good idea to make visitors wait for registration at your site in queue. I think you should configure your server to handle thousands of requests easily, and it should be as it is a dedicated server.

My above details are just an idea and is just to give you a heads up that how you can implement it.

I hope it will help you

Thank you

Answer (score -2):

I could use one to prevent overload of server better let them try later than never. 1-3 mio. visitors a month advertising banner with a 2-15% answer rate is 150-450000 visitors a month with advertising so would be nice on peak times to be able to say we have so many visitors in numbers so we ask you to wait until the peak is over and then come back. And also tell them it's in order to prevent server crash